# Ansible : how to create a function like

Tags: ansible

I have a repeated pattern like this one::

```
- name: =code_01= clone repository
  git: repo=gitolite@git.site.net:/code_01
       dest=/tmp/code_01
       update=yes
       force=yes
       accept_hostkey=yes
       version=master
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: "{{ user }}"

- name: =code_01= egg build
  shell: . {{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}/bin/activate && make egg
  args:
    chdir: "/tmp/code_01"
  sudo_user: "{{ user }}"
  sudo: true

- name: =code_01= egg get
  command: find /tmp/code_01/dist -type f -iname '*.egg'
  register: code_01eggs

- name: =code_01= egg install in {{ venv_name }} venv
  shell: . {{ home }}/{{ venv_name }}/bin/activate && easy_install {{ item }}
  args:
    chdir: "{{ home }}"
  with_items: "{{ code_01eggs.stdout_lines }}"
  sudo_user: "{{ user }}"
  sudo: true

- name: =code_01= cleanup
  file: path=/tmp/code_01 state=absent
  sudo: true
```

And I have this to do with:  **code_02**,  **code_03**,  **code_04**, ..., **code_0n**

How can I "factorize" this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can move the logic to a second yml file and use `include` with `with_items`:

```
- include: factored.yml
  with_items:
    - code_01
    - code_02
    - code_03
```

And in the second file replace `code_01` with `{{ item }}`.

Useful link: [Ansible docs: Loops and include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#loops-and-includes-in-2-0)

Note: if you have nested loops, you can set the outter loop item using `set_fact` after Ansible 2.0. Refer to the above documentation for more.

Comment: isn't it possible to have Object approach? extract each call to function like so this file ( controller like ) should be short and readable?